How can I remove the cookie in the browser when using next js and express
I am working with this project that uses nextjs app dir as frontend and express for the backend. The BE returns a jwt token for authentication and putting it in the cookie using res.cookie("authorization", "token"). When using the api in next and it is used by a client component, the BE checks the request first in its middleware if the cookie is still valid. If it is not valid anymore the be will remove the cookie using res.cookie("authorization", "", { maxAge: 1 }); and return some json. When the response is sent from the browser, the authorization cookie in the browser is removed.
My problem is when I use server components. I will use the api in the server component and when the BE middleware said the cookie is not valid it will again use this res.cookie("authorization", "", { maxAge: 1 }); and return some json. However, when the response is received by the browser it does not remove the authorization cookie in the browser. How can I remove it in the browser? Thank you!

Tried intercepting the axios response and try to delete it there but nothing happens
Tried accessing the response in next js middleware but failed since I think it only run what is accessed in the url.
Tried setting the cookie in nextjs routehandler but it only remove the authorization cookie when accesing the api directly in the browser http://localhost:300/api/todos but when accessed in the server component via fetch() it does not remove the cookies but only return the json.


When working with server components in Next.js, you cannot directly interact with the browser's cookies from the server-side code. Server components run on the server, and they do not have direct access to the client-side browser environment or its cookies.
To remove the authorization cookie from the browser when using server components in Next.js, you need to rely on the backend (Express) to handle the cookie removal and send the appropriate response headers.

I already made express remove the cookie by using res.cookie to remove the token in the cookie and it works when my component is a client component. What do you mean by appropriate response headers?

try {
    const res = NextResponse.json({
        message: "Logout succefully",
        success: true,
    });
    
    res.cookies.set("token","",{httpOnly: true, expires: new Date(0)});
    return res;
}


hi, can you please include an explanation of what this snippet does?
